# Magento 2 - How to manually upgrade extensions packaged in ZIP files

Tags: magento-2.1

I have an extension I bought that is distributed via a zip file. I installed it just fine, but shortly after they released an updated version.

I can't find any guide online for manually upgrading extensions. I would use the same process used for install, but from what i've ready I get the impression that things like DB tables might not get cleaned / updated properly if I use the exact same steps I used for install.

FYI - I looked and the extension does not include an UninstallSchema.php file, but does include an InstallSchema.php and UpdateSchema.php that I want to make sure gets ran.

Answer (score 0):

You should reach out the Vendor for an upgraded zip, since you had paid for it anyway. They should at least be able to tell you if the upgrade would cause any side effects on the existing setup and what is the best way to avoid any data loss.